# Problem with roslaunch after upgrading to Gazebo-1.8 & DRCSim-2.6

Tags: gazebo-1.8

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Today I upgraded to Gazebo-1.8 and DRCSim-2.6 and now I encounter a problem after running
"roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch".
Gazebo fails to start properly and freezes in a gray screen then dies. This the message I get:

```
  [ WARN] [1369173843.179656077]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
  [ WARN] [1369173843.179814558]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
  [ WARN] [1369173843.179845859]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
  [ WARN] [1369173843.179875473]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
  [gazebo-1] process has finished cleanly
```

Thanks for any help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2922/problem-with-roslaunch-after-upgrading-to-gazebo-1.8-&-drcsim-2.6/) by [Zara](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/32/zara/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My first guess is that you're using a non-NVIDIA GPU.  There are [reports](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/283/drcsim-recently-stopped-working-with-intel) that the change in drcsim 2.6 to using the GPU for laser scan generation causes gazebo to crash immediately on Intel GPUs.

There's a [proposed patch](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/317/files-for-cpu-lidar/diff) that adds launch files to let you bring up simulation using the CPU-based laser.  You might try that.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zara](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/32/zara/) on 2013-05-22**:
I have two laptops with Intel GPUs and they both show same issue with launching atlas. I will try to use that patch. Thanks. By the way, how can downgrade to DRCSim-2.5?

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-05-23**:
All previous releases are [archived](http://gazebosim.org/assets/distributions/).  You can download the `.deb` files for specific versions and install them manually with `dpkg`, instead of `apt-get`.  If you go back to drcsim 2.5.x, also go back to gazebo 1.7.x and sandia-hand 5.1.13.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had this problem with the latest (stable) version of gazebo (1.8.0) and drcsim (2.6.1).  I also had an error about the connection manager - possibly also related to this question [[link]](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2388/drcsim-drcsim-nightly-cant-roslaunch-either/).

The solution for me:  My laptop has two graphics cards - Intel and NVidia, and it uses optimius to power save.  In Ubuntu, only the Intel video card could be used. I installed the nvidia-current driver and then disabled optimus in BIOS, and everything works perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [KS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/358/ks/) with karma: 11 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1